# not able to get client secret id from console.developers.google.com for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-console-developer

Not able to get client secret id from console.developers.google.com for iOS. Its not providing client secret id.

---

Any suggestion for

```
 [_googleOAuth authorizeUserWithClienID:@"clientid" 
                        andClientSecret:@"secretid" 
                          andParentView:self.view 
                              andScopes:[NSArray 
                        arrayWithObject:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]];
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue, do you got any solution?

Comment: I solved this by creating by creating oath credentials by selecting web application and used its client secret id in my app and started working.    https://console.developers.google.com/project/icare4u-1091/apiui/credential/oauthclient?authuser=0

Comment: @AkleshRathaur it gives me redirect_uri_mismatch when I use client id and  secret created for web app.

Comment: @Warewolf create client id for mobile app and client secret id for web app.